# Show that $T'$ is a topology on Y

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a map and let $T$ be a topology on $X$.

Show that $$T'=\{U\subseteq Y \mid f^{-1}(U)\in T\} $$ is a topology on $Y$.

$T'$ is the finest topology on $Y$ such that the map $f:(X, T) \rightarrow (Y, T') $ is continuous.

$$$$

We have to show:

1.The set Y and
the empty set are elements of T' .

2. Any union of elements of T' belongs to T'.
3. Any finite intersection of elements of T' belongs to T'

We have the following :

1. holds by the definition of T'.

For 2):

Let $ \{ U_\alpha\mid \alpha\in I\}$ be a non-empty collection of elements of $T'$.

We have to show that $O=\bigcup\limits_{\alpha\in I} U_\alpha\in T'$.

If one of the $U_\alpha$ is $\Bbb R$, so is the union, and then $O\in T'$.

If all $U_\alpha=\emptyset$, then $O=\emptyset\in T'$.

Otherwise, let $\beta=\sup\{\alpha\mid\alpha\in I\}$.  If $\beta=\infty$, then $O=\Bbb R\in T'$.  If $\beta$ is finite, then $O=(-\infty,\beta)\in T'$.

3. For the nontrivial case where no member of the finite collection of sets is empty, given a finite collection $\{(-\infty,\alpha_1),\ldots, (-\infty,\alpha_k)\}$ of elements in $T'$, the intersection is $(-\infty, \min\{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k \})\in T'$.

Is everything correct?

Comment: You were working in abstract sets not $\Bbb R$!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you reach $\mathbb{R}$ from the setting of general topological spaces $X$ and $Y$? Also, how do you know that the supremum of $I$ exists? For all we know, $I$ is an arbitrary indexing set (without a partial order).

The thing to do is that look at the union, which you call $O = \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in I} U_{\alpha}$. Then, by definition, this set is in $T'$ if and only if its pre-image (under $f$) is in $T$. So, look at $f^{-1} \left( O \right)$. Since union (and intersection) behaves well under pre-images, we have

$$f^{-1} \left( O \right) = f^{-1} \left( \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in I} U_{\alpha} \right) = \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in I} f^{-1} \left( U_{\alpha} \right).$$

But, since each $U_{\alpha}$ is in $T'$, their pre-images, i.e., $f^{-1} \left( U_{\alpha} \right)$ are in $T$. And because $T$ is a topology, their (arbitrary) union is again in $T$. Hence, $O$ is in $T'$.

Similarly, for finite intersection, you only need to look at the intersection of two sets in $T'$. Since intersection also behaves nicely under pre-images, similar argument leads us to the proof.

Comment: As for the first property, that $Y$ and the emptyset must be contained. We have that $Y\subseteq Y$ and does it follow that $f^{-1}(Y)\in T$ from the definition that $T$ is a topology?

Comment: I tried that the way of argumenting also at a similar exercise, could you please check also that one? Here is the link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4112011/show-that-t-is-a-topology-on-x

Comment: What is $f^{-1} \left( X \right)$? If you take the pre-image of the codomain universe, what can you get? Will there be some elements from the domain universe that will be left out?

Comment: Will it not be the whole domain?

Comment: Exactly! So, the whole domain $X$ is anyway inside $T$, right? Similarly for the emptyset.

Comment: Thank you very much!! :-)